# How to solve this hyperbolic trig equation iteratively?

Tags: equation-solving

i need the "a" value from this solver and it isnt working. i know a should be between 0 and 5, most likely around 1. The other values im not as sure of but y20 and y10 should be negative numbers around .5... also x10 and x20 should be positive between 0 and 1.

```
    \[Mu]m = .085/.05; l1 = .61; l2 = .595; x2 = .968;
NMinimize[{Norm[
1 - (a \[Mu]m (Sinh[(x10 - xm)/a] + Sinh[(xm - x20)/a]))] + 
Norm[a Cosh[-x10/a] + y10] + Norm[a Cosh[(x2 - x20)/a] + y20] + 
Norm[l1 - a Sinh[(xm - x10)/a]] + 
Norm[l2 - a (Sinh[(x2 - x20)/a] - Sinh[(xm - x20)/a])] + 
Norm[a Cosh[(xm - x10)/a] + y10 - (a Cosh[(x20 - xm)/a] + y20)], 
0 < a < 1.5 && -.7 < y20 < 0 && -.7 < y10 < 0 && -.5 < x10 < .5 && 
0 < x20 < 1.5}, {x10, x20, xm, y10, y20, a}, 
Method -> "RandomSearch", MaxIterations -> 10^4]
```

Comment: This seems to be the same as the other question, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188018/large-solve-function-on-mathematica-not-working-with-hyperbolic-trig-functions -- Why don't you just edit that question?

Comment: because the guy answering my questions stopped answering

Answer (score 2):

The [`Norm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Norm.html) of a scalar is its absolute value. Look at

```
Plot[Norm[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

or

```
Assuming[Element[x, Reals], Norm[x] == Abs[x] // Simplify]

(* True *)
```

[`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) all of the input values so you can freely set the [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) within [`NMinimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html)

```
μm = 17/10; l1 = 61/100; l2 = 119/200; x2 = 121/125;

SeedRandom[0]

NMinimize[{Norm[1 - (a μm (Sinh[(x10 - xm)/a] + Sinh[(xm - x20)/a]))] + 
   Norm[a Cosh[-x10/a] + y10] + Norm[a Cosh[(x2 - x20)/a] + y20] + 
   Norm[l1 - a Sinh[(xm - x10)/a]] + 
   Norm[l2 - a (Sinh[(x2 - x20)/a] - Sinh[(xm - x20)/a])] + 
   Norm[a Cosh[(xm - x10)/a] + y10 - (a Cosh[(x20 - xm)/a] + y20)], 
  0 < a < 3/2 && -7/10 < y20 < 0 && -7/10 < y10 < 0 && -1/2 < x10 < 1/2 && 
   0 < x20 < 3/2}, {x10, x20, xm, y10, y20, a}, Method -> "RandomSearch", 
 MaxIterations -> 10^4, WorkingPrecision -> 15]

(* {1.39865516132942, {x10 -> 0.309535491165357, x20 -> 0.209668869240626, 
  xm -> 0.780022142278469, y10 -> -0.505720397617272, 
  y20 -> -0.700000000000000, a -> 0.367452643220535}} *)
```

Note that the value of `y20` is on the boundary of the specified region which suggests the boundary should be extended.

```
SeedRandom[0]

NMinimize[{Norm[1 - (a μm (Sinh[(x10 - xm)/a] + Sinh[(xm - x20)/a]))] + 
   Norm[a Cosh[-x10/a] + y10] + Norm[a Cosh[(x2 - x20)/a] + y20] + 
   Norm[l1 - a Sinh[(xm - x10)/a]] + 
   Norm[l2 - a (Sinh[(x2 - x20)/a] - Sinh[(xm - x20)/a])] + 
   Norm[a Cosh[(xm - x10)/a] + y10 - (a Cosh[(x20 - xm)/a] + y20)], 
  0 < a < 3/2 && -2 < y20 < 0 && -7/10 < y10 < 0 && -1/2 < x10 < 1/2 && 
   0 < x20 < 3/2}, {x10, x20, xm, y10, y20, a}, Method -> "RandomSearch", 
 MaxIterations -> 10^4, WorkingPrecision -> 15]

(* {0.555324594222433, {x10 -> 0.437309657997211, x20 -> 0.259460028813828, 
  xm -> 0.860835239258215, y10 -> -0.699888088071041, 
  y20 -> -1.27035142037279, a -> 0.277340960805850}} *)
```

The minimum is still far from zero so there does not appear to be a root of your equations in the specified region.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
\[Mu]m=400;l1=1;l2=1;x2=1;
NMinimize[{
  Norm[1-(a \[Mu]m (Sinh[(x10 - xm)/a] + Sinh[(xm - x20)/a]))]+
  Norm[a Cosh[-x10/a] + y10]+ Norm[a Cosh[(x2 - x20)/a] + y20]+
  Norm[l1-a Sinh[(xm - x10)/a]]+
  Norm[l2-a (Sinh[(x2 - x20)/a] - Sinh[(xm - x20)/a])]+
  Norm[a Cosh[(xm - x10)/a] + y10-(a Cosh[(x20 - xm)/a] + y20)],
  0<a<5&&-5<y20<0&&-5<y10<0&&0<x10<1&&0<x20<1},
  {x10, x20, xm, y10, y20, a},Method->"RandomSearch",MaxIterations->10^4]

(*{1.2065, {x10->0.0337, x20->0.0312, xm->0.1626, y10->-2.4356, y20->-2.4339, a -> 2.4354}}*)
```

Now 1.2065 is a very poor approximation of a zero minimum but you might be able to play with your constraints on your six variables and get it to find a zero or you might get fairly strong feelings that there is no zero in the region you suggest.

Comment: little confused. you want me to play with the constraints and try to get the 1.2065 to zero?

Comment: yes makes more sense now, im trying 0 < a < 2 && -1 < y20 < 0 && -1 < y10 < 0 && -1 < x10 < .5 && 
  0 < x20 < 2} now

Comment: but im trying to get the 1.2065 to go to zero right ?

Comment: i have updated the code in the question. can you show me what you mean by adding Abs? Im confused because there is already a Norm there

Comment: using the new code in the question

Comment: so should i change all the norms to abs?

Comment: would better ranges be smaller ranges?

Comment: Better ranges are where the surface is smooth with few or no local minima and where there are one or more zeros within the range, BUT you don't know where or even if there is such a place

Comment: The norm of the jacobian is around 10^8, so a large residual might not be so unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

[`Norm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Norm.html) is not a differentiable function, and it's usually better to use a sum of squares for real-valued functions:

```
Clear[μm, l1, l2, x2];
objOP = Norm[1 - (a μm (Sinh[(x10 - xm)/a] + Sinh[(xm - x20)/a]))] + 
   Norm[a Cosh[-x10/a] + y10] + 
   Norm[a Cosh[(x2 - x20)/a] + y20] + 
   Norm[l1 - a Sinh[(xm - x10)/a]] + 
   Norm[l2 - a (Sinh[(x2 - x20)/a] - Sinh[(xm - x20)/a])] + 
   Norm[a Cosh[(xm - x10)/a] + y10 - (a Cosh[(x20 - xm)/a] + y20)];
objSS = objOP /. Norm -> (#^2 &);

μm = .085/.05; l1 = .61; l2 = .595; x2 = .968;

NMinimize[{objOP, 
  0 < a < 5 && -5 < y20 < 0 && -5 < y10 < 0 && 0 < x10 < 1 && 0 < x20 < 1},
 {x10, x20, xm, y10, y20, a}, 
 Method -> "RandomSearch", MaxIterations -> 10^4]

{min, sol} = NMinimize[{objSS, 
   0 < a < 5 && -5 < y20 < 0 && -5 < y10 < 0 && 0 < x10 < 1 && 0 < x20 < 1},
 {x10, x20, xm, y10, y20, a}, 
  Method -> "RandomSearch", MaxIterations -> 10^4]
objOP /. sol
(*
  {0.3519, {x10 -> 0.511012, x20 -> 0.324884, xm -> 0.898573, 
    y10 -> -0.931345, y20 -> -1.51882, a -> 0.264148}}

  {2.83993*10^-19, {x10 -> 0.51201, x20 -> 0.376215, xm -> 0.885239, 
    y10 -> -1.23342, y20 -> -1.80519, a -> 0.207372}}

  1.15893*10^-9
*)
```

In the OP's example, the sum-of-squares solution is much better.

Comment: +1 I believe that the equivalent to `Norm` is `Norm -> (Sqrt[#^2]&)`. Although the use of `Norm -> (#^2&)` increases the penalty for large deviation and provides better results in this case.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks. Yes, I chose `Norm -> (#^2&)` because Newton's method, which I believe is used to process the random points when the function is differentiable, will probably behave optimally when the minima-zeros are quadratic ($f_{min} + \sum \Delta x^2 + O(\Delta x^3)$.